# Map occurrence in C++

Tags: c++

In the below code I can always print out the "number of occurrences" of a number in the vector. If you print out you will see that, it's printing all the numbers in the vector elements that are repeated or even did not repeat at all too.

The print out number would be:

```
1: 0                                                                       
2: 4                                                                       
5: 5                                                                       
6: 2 3                                                                     
7: 6 7 8 9                                                                 
8: 1 10
```

What I'm interested in is that I can always find the difference between the vector position [i] from the printed array:

```
cout << occurrences[6][0] - occurrences[6][1]  << endl;
```

In the above case, I did take the "location difference" between the first position of element "6" and the second position of element "6". But how can I do this without knowing the numbers that printed out? I mean I will want to find the "position difference" between the first and second repetitive numbers (if there is any, for example, because 0 did not repeat twice, so I won't consider that number or I won't find the difference of that number as well)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> ar{ 1, 8, 6, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 };
  map<int, vector<size_t> > occurrences{ };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i) {
    occurrences[ar[i]].push_back(i);
  }

  for (const auto& occurrence:occurrences) {
    cout << occurrence.first << ": ";
    for (auto index: occurrence.second) {
      cout << index << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. With that being said, your question is very difficult to understand.   What exactly is the problem you are trying to code for? Please don't make us read your previous question.  Just start off a question assuming we have to context.  State the problem you are trying to solve. The input you are using, and the expected output.  Define what you mean by an "occurrence".  And so on.

Comment: I think if you applied the [Rubber Duck Methodology](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/), you'll be able to phrase your question better.

Comment: Hello all, I have solved that problem, so I updated the question folwing your suggestions. let me know if it is okay now?

Comment: This needs to be prefaced with the following clearer explanation:   "I would like to make a list of all the positions at which some number appears in an array.  For example, in the the array `{ 1, 8, 6, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 }`, the number `2` appears at array index `4`, and the number `8` appears two times, at array index `1` and array index `10`.  If you map each unique number in the array to its list of indices at which it occurs then you would have... (_and then show your example_)."  Then people might have a hope of understanding the rest of your question.

Comment: I can't understand the sentence where you wrote the typo: "_wit_".  Did you mean "How can I do _this_ **without** knowing the _numbers_?"  If so, what do _this_ and _numbers_ refer to in that sentence?  Please clarify what you are asking.  It sounds like you want to determine the distance between the first occurrence and second occurrence of a number.  Or perhaps you are trying to determine the distance between the first occurrence and the _last_ occurrence.  It's just not clear.

Comment: Also, you are using the word _multiplicity_ incorrectly - I suggest you don't use that word.  That sentence needs to be rewritten and expressed more clearly.  I think you just mean "number of occurrences" or "number of times a given value appears in the array".

Comment: I have updated accordingly Wyck.

Comment: @zero_field I don't understand your problem. In your code, for each number, `occurrence.second` is a vector of its indexes. You can simply work with this vector (e.g., find distances between indexes) without knowing the number. Is it what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I want to consider only the numbers that occurrences twice. And then I would like to find the difference between the vector indices.

Comment: @zero_field Twice or multiple times? Then, simply add `if (occurences.second.size() == 2) ...` (or, `> 1`). The differences of indexes in the original vector `ar` correspond with the differences of `occurences` vector elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you are missing here is find() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Assuming you only want to find the distance between 1st two occurrences, I updated you code to the following,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> ar{ 1, 8, 6, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8 };
  map<int, vector<size_t> > occurrences;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i) {
    auto iter = occurrences.find(ar[i]);
    if (iter == occurrences.end()) {
      occurrences[ar[i]].push_back(i);
    }
    else { //print the distance between the current and the previous occurrence
      cout << "distance with first occurrence of number "  << ar[i] << " is " << (i - iter->second[0]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is great, and what I want. How Can I ignore taking the difference when the number appearance for the first time? I tried like this `cout <<(iter->second[1] - iter->second[0])<<endl;` , but it is printing some pointer address.